# Parameterized Initializer Reflection in Swift

Tags: swift, reflection

I am trying to apply reflection on a swift class (someClass) to invoke an init method that takes one argument (someArg), I managed to get the init selector and IMP that has 1 argument, but when I invoke the IMP it ends up calling the init with no arguments. In the Playground below I always get "called the wrong init" printed.
If I remove the override init I get the following error:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class '__lldb_expr_15.someClass'
```

What am I missing?

```
import UIKit

public class someClass:NSObject{
    init( num:someArg){
        print("called the right init")
    }

    override init(){
        print("called the wrong init")
    }
}

public class someArg:NSObject{
    override init(){

    }
}


public class Test{

    func reflect(){

        let classType: NSObject.Type = someClass.self as NSObject.Type
        let  (initializerWithOneArgImp,selector)  = getInitializerWithArguments(classType, argumentsCount: 1)

        typealias initializerWithOneArgImpType =  @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector, AnyObject) -> (AnyObject)

        let callback = unsafeBitCast(initializerWithOneArgImp , initializerWithOneArgImpType.self)
        callback(classType,selector,someArg())
    }

    func getInitializerWithArguments(classType:AnyClass, argumentsCount:Int)->(IMP,Selector){

        var methodCount:CUnsignedInt = 0
        let methodList = class_copyMethodList(classType.self, &methodCount)
        let n : Int = Int(methodCount)

        for var i: Int = 0; i < n; i++ {

            let methodSelector = method_getName(methodList[i])
            let methodName:String = String(_sel:methodSelector)

            if(methodName == "init")
            {
                let methodArgumentsCount = method_getNumberOfArguments(methodList[i])

                if(methodArgumentsCount  == UInt32(argumentsCount) + 1)
                {
                    return (method_getImplementation(methodList[i]),methodSelector)

                }
            }
        }
        return (nil,nil)
    }
}
var test = Test()
test.reflect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the non parametrized init has two arguments by default, and the parameterized init would have "initWithNum" as methodName.

```
if(methodName.hasPrefix("init"))
{
     let methodArgumentsCount = method_getNumberOfArguments(methodList[i])

     if(methodArgumentsCount  == UInt32(argumentsCount) + 2)
     {
            return (method_getImplementation(methodList[i]),methodSelector)

      }
 }
```